# splitting an array into variables

Tags: arrays, perl, variables, split

I am weak when it comes to splitting the fields of an array (`array[0]` - `array[6]`)wal
into varialbles in perl

This is the end of a large program  - the results get pumped in to an array, and then emailed in a tabular format - the array that gets pumped out looks like the static `@mailarray` below. The table gets formatted ok in the email, it just pumps out the same line  - for each line of the array. It needs to traverse the whole array 7 fields to each line.

```
mrktsrvr:ltick Chicago tkscan100:tmscn-Brooklyn OCOMsg2
mrktsrvr:ltick Chicago tkscan100:tmscn-Brooklyn OCOMsg2
mrktsrvr:ltick Chicago tkscan100:tmscn-Brooklyn OCOMsg2
mrktsrvr:ltick Chicago tkscan100:tmscn-Brooklyn OCOMsg2
mrktsrvr:ltick Chicago tkscan100:tmscn-Brooklyn OCOMsg2
mrktsrvr:ltick Chicago tkscan100:tmscn-Brooklyn OCOMsg2
```

The end of the program looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

@mailarray = qw(mrktsrvr ltick Chicago tkscan100 tmscn Brooklyn OCOMsg2
mrktsrvr ltick Chicago ctdb811 dltic080 Brooklyn OCOMsg2
mrktsrvr ltick Chicago farm101 bhsrv0 Brooklyn OCOMsg2
mrktsrvr ltick Chicago farm102 bhsrv0 Brooklyn OCOMsg2
mrktsrvr ltick Chicago rnds110 nictsrv1 Brooklyn OCOMsg2
mrktsrvr ltick Chicago relay11 tryticUS1 Brooklyn OCOMsg2);
($header_host, $header_process, $header_host_region, $stat_host, $stat_process, $stat_region, $stat_message_type)=@mailarray;
print $header_host;
print "@mailarray\n";
if (@mailarray){
  #open(MAIL,"| /usr/sbin/sendmail -t") || warn "Can't send email\n";
  print  "to:casper\@mail\n";
  print  "from: $header_host\n";
  print  "Subject: ping_stat for $header_host $yyyymmdd\n";
  print  "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
  print  "&lt;html&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;center&gt;&lt;b&gt;ping_stat messaging violations for $header_host $yyyymmdd&lt;/b&gt;\n";
  print  "&lt;table border=1&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Process&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;Acceptable Regions&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;Violation of Region&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;Message Type&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;\n";
  foreach (@mailarray){
        ($header_host, $header_process, $header_host_region, $stat_host, $stat_process, $stat_region, $stat_message_type)=@mailarray;
#split(/\s+/, $_);
        print  "&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;$header_process" . ":" . "$header_process&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;$header_host_region&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;$stat_host" .":". "$stat_process" . "-" . "$stat_region&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;$stat_message_type&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;\n";
  }
  print  "&lt;/table&gt;\n";
  print  "&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;\n";
  print "&lt;/table&gt;&lt;/center&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;";
  close ;
}
```

Comment: I must say that I have no idea what your question is. I've read what you've written back and forth, and nothing.

Comment: I knew what I needed but I did not know how to explain it - the array had thousands of elements, but i needed to break it down every fourth element and populate an html table. using splice on the array did the trick

Comment: i had to use something like this:
    while (my \@stat_array_row = splice(\@stat_array_rows, 0, 4)) {

Comment: thanks for trying to understand the problem though.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, your problem is that you don't know how to split those strings - this is doing it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str = <<END
mrktsrvr:ltick Chicago tkscan100:tmscn-Brooklyn OCOMsg2
mrktsrvr:ltick Chicago tkscan100:tmscn-Brooklyn OCOMsg2
mrktsrvr:ltick Chicago tkscan100:tmscn-Brooklyn OCOMsg2
mrktsrvr:ltick Chicago tkscan100:tmscn-Brooklyn OCOMsg2
mrktsrvr:ltick Chicago tkscan100:tmscn-Brooklyn OCOMsg2
mrktsrvr:ltick Chicago tkscan100:tmscn-Brooklyn OCOMsg2
END
;

foreach my $line ( split( /\n/, $str ) ){
    my @array = split( /\W/, $line);
    print Dumper(\@array);
}
```

Comment: +1, But instead of `@array` wouldn't he want his original: `($header_host, $header_process, $header_host_region, $stat_host, $stat_process, $stat_region, $stat_message_type)` for the formatted printing? Also, is it better to print the array ref using Dumper, or makes no difference?

Answer (score 1):

You should have used an array of arrays.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @mailarray = (
    [qw/ mrktsrvr ltick Chicago tkscan100 tmscn Brooklyn OCOMsg2 /],
    [qw/ mrktsrvr ltick Chicago ctdb811 dltic080 Brooklyn OCOMsg2 /],
    [qw/ mrktsrvr ltick Chicago farm101 bhsrv0 Brooklyn OCOMsg2 /],
    [qw/ mrktsrvr ltick Chicago farm102 bhsrv0 Brooklyn OCOMsg2 /],
    [qw/ mrktsrvr ltick Chicago rnds110 nictsrv1 Brooklyn OCOMsg2 /],
    [qw/ mrktsrvr ltick Chicago relay11 tryticUS1 Brooklyn OCOMsg2 /],
);

for (@mailarray) {
    print Dumper \@$_;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i understand your question, but if you want to know a way how to extract seven array fields to variables, this should work:

```
for(my $i = 0; $i < @mailarray; $i += 7){
 my ($header_host, $header_process, $header_host_region, 
     $stat_host, $stat_process, $stat_region, 
     $stat_message_type) = @mailarray[$i..$i+7];
     print "&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;$header_process:" .
       "$header_process&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;".
       "$header_host_region&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;$stat_host".
       ":$stat_process"."-"."$stat_region&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;".
       "$stat_message_type&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;\n"
}
```

btw: think of

1. …*HERE-Docs* using them makes it a lot of easier to write literal multiline strings (you can see them in a previous post)
2. … using a better data structure e.g. a List of Hashes
3. … formatting your code properly, your string literals are already divided with dots, why not putting a newline there?

Comment: for(my $i = 0; $i < @mailarray; $i += 7){
 my ($header_host, $header_process, $header_host_region, 
     $stat_host, $stat_process, $stat_region, 
     $stat_message_type) = @mailarray[$i..$i+7];
     print "&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;$header_process:" .
       "$header_process&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;".
       "$header_host_region&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;$stat_host".
       ":$stat_process"."-"."$stat_region&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;".
       "$stat_message_type&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;\n"
}

Comment: @casper: I'm not sure what you want to tell me…

Comment: sorry about that i wanted to post a comment but had some trouble commenting it